# Extracting images from HTML from <div> using Tika

Tags: java, apache, xhtml, apache-tika

I have the following xhtml file, which contains about 30-40 images.  The file is auto-generated and the numbers of the image will change, but the {html text} content which should really be  do not change.  I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

I'm trying to parse/find these images to rename them from image#.png to {html text}.png.

Substring of the HTML:

```
<div class="s8a6d62e8" style="">Top 10 ARP sources in terms of bits.</div>
<div class="sbeea9846" style="">
    <img style="width: 701px; height: 526px; border: 0px" src="Final Test Report_3.files\Final Test Report_34.Png"></img>
</div>
<div class="s306f0049" style="">Figure 3 - Top Ten ARP MAC Sources</div>
<div class="s12d95b95" style="">
    <a name="Top Ten ARP MAC Destinations"><br></a>
</div>
<div class="s1a75bf07" style="">Top Ten ARP MAC Destinations</div>
<div class="s8a6d62e8" style="">Top 10 ARP destinations in terms of bits.</div>
<div class="sbeea9846" style="">
    <img style="width: 701px; height: 526px; border: 0px" src="Final Test Report_3.files\Final Test Report_35.Png"></img>
</div>
<div class="s306f0049" style="">Figure 4 - Top Ten ARP MAC Destinations</div>
<div class="s1a75bf07" style="">ARP MAC Conversations</div>
<div class="s8a6d62e8" style="">Conversation ring with ARP endpoints and conversations.</div>
<div class="sbeea9846" style="">
    <img style="width: 701px; height: 526px; border: 0px" src="Final Test Report_3.files\Final Test Report_36.Png"></img>
</div>
<div class="s306f0049" style="">Figure 5 - ARP MAC Conversations</div>
```

The output I would like is as follows:

```
Final Test Report_3.files\Top Ten ARP MAC Sources.Png
Final Test Report_3.files\Top Ten ARP MAC Destinations.Png
Final Test Report_3.files\ARP MAC Conversations.Png
```

etc.,

Comment: Note that the <img> tab is before the <div> tag where the title is.  The title appears below the image.

Comment: http://tika.apache.org/1.2/parser.html seems to generate SAX events, so you need to store the src attribute in a state variable when the IMG tag is encountered, couple it with the #CDATA of the next DIV tag and push it to a list, and clear the state variable.

Comment: My only issue with that would if it's SAX, why not just use SAX -- why use Tika at all?

Comment: Tika's HTMLParser seems to be a bit tolerant compared to traditional SAX parser, when it comes to parsing HTML snippets. SAX throws exception if HTML snippet is not a well-formed XML, where Tika can happily parse the snippet you posted in the question.

Comment: Seems like Tika was just not designed for what I'm asking it for.  It isn't designed to parse the whole document. "div" elements are skipped, "content" of tags are ignored.  I would have to rewrite most of the handlers to get it to do what I need.

Comment: Right, I too realized that `div`s are being skipped. Not sure why? If not, my solution to parse the IMG and DIV would have worked perfectly.

Comment: Because "The <div> elements contain no inherent semantic meaning" not sure why that is the case, but that's the reason that was posted.

Comment: Is the formation of html something you can modify?

Comment: No, it's generated externally.